# concatenate one file from the same line of the other file using script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

cat test1.txt

```
abc
```

cat test2.txt

```
def
```

I have above two files and trying to append test2.txt to test1.txt but every time it is appending into new line, I tried to find the solution from web but coudn't able to get proper answer please let me know if anyone can help me out to find the solution

I want output in this format
Output : `"abc,def"` in test1.txt file

Tried with the cat and echo commands with the possible solutions given in web but it is not working

Answer (score 4):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test1
abc

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test2
def

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ paste -d "," test1 test2
abc,def

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ pr -mtJS"," test1 test2
abc,def
```

Comment: Good use of underutilized `pr` utility ++